# UITableViewDiffableDataSource is not calling tableView(_:commit:forRowAt:)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

There is a `UITableView` that uses `UITableViewDiffableDataSource`. I subclassed `UITableViewDiffableDataSource` to add `canEditRowAt`. This correctly shows the swipeable delete action when gesturing the row. However, clicking the delete option does not call [`tableView(_:commit:forRowAt:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdiffabledatasource/3375816-tableview#). I have [read](https://blog.schiavo.me/posts/coredata-diffabledatasource/) that you have to use `tableView(_:trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt:indexPath:)` because the other function is not supported. I wanted to confirm that was true. If we subclass `tableView(_:commit:forRowAt:)` as well, we need a clean way to call a function on the original View Controller.

```
// MyViewController
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
      // Delete cell
    }
}
// Subclass DiffableDataSource used in MyViewController
final class CustomDiffableDatasource: UITableViewDiffableDataSource<MyViewController.Section, MyViewController.Item> {
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        guard let item = itemIdentifier(for: indexPath) else {
            return false
        }
        return item.isEditable
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the custom `trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt`func looks like for adding a delete swipe. I saw this in another StackOverflow question that referenced a [blog post](https://iosdevcenters.blogspot.com/2018/01/table-swipe-actions-in-swift-4-using.html).

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
        guard self.dataSource?.tableView(tableView, canEditRowAt: indexPath) == true else {
            return nil
        }
        
        let delete = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") { [weak self] action, view, success in
            self?.remove(at: indexPath)
            success(true)
        }
        
        let swipeActionConfig = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [delete])
        swipeActionConfig.performsFirstActionWithFullSwipe = false
        
        return swipeActionConfig
    }
```